# Android questions on superuser getting closed as "not computer related"

Tags: discussion, android

Android questions on superuser are getting closed as "not computer related". Examples:

- https://superuser.com/questions/116579/does-terminal-emulator-work-the-same-as-android-debug-bridge-closed
- https://superuser.com/questions/116960/htc-android-mail-imap-folders-not-synchronous-closed
- https://superuser.com/questions/115514/on-demand-rtsp-to-android-closed
- https://superuser.com/questions/114340/is-there-a-database-app-for-android-and-if-not-whats-the-problem-closed
- https://superuser.com/questions/115739/android-mail-app-thread-vs-conversation-closed

Lots more on https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/android, almost all of them are closed as "not computer related".

The [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) states: "Super User [...] is not about [...] cellphones or mobile devices, except smartphones such as iPhone that interface with your computer"

However:

- Android per se is just a platform, an [operating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)). It's not a device.
- [Android runs on lots of devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Android_devices), [including netbooks](http://gizmodo.com/5381868/acer-aspire-one-aod250-boots-android-and-win-xp-holds-us-over-until-chrome-os-arrives) and even [standard x86 architectures](http://www.androidx86.org/) (any PC). Android is *fundamentally* different from iPhone because of this, so the same criteria for superuser questions cannot be applied.
- Android devices *do* interface with other computers (via TCP/IP, HTTP, IMAP, and any standard protocol) just like any other computer, because *they are computers*.

Let's pick one of the closed questions: https://superuser.com/questions/116960/htc-android-mail-imap-folders-not-synchronous-closed . How is this different from a question about Thunderbird or Outlook?

Another: https://superuser.com/questions/115514/on-demand-rtsp-to-android-closed . How is it different from a question about any RTSP client/server on a PC or MAC ?

Other similar meta questions on this topic:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13289/is-asking-phone-questions-permitted-on-superuser
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16087/are-iphone-ipod-ipod-touch-questions-computer-related-superuser

I think either the FAQ has to be revised to be more clear about this, or the moderators need to be moderated.

Comment: Who moderates the moderators?

Comment: @Ether - The answer to your question is here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/

Comment: @diago apparently you can't ask about Zunes, even though you can only use them via the Zune Software which... only runs on Windows PCs. http://superuser.com/questions/119566/anybody-know-how-to-get-podcasts-sorted-correctly-on-a-zune-closed  Seriously?  I'm pissed off about this.

Comment: @Will Well actually I can only officially put music on my iPhone via ITunes on Windows or the Mac, should I use the same argument to keep the iPhone questions open?

Answer (score 12):

Did you know about this one?

[Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/):

> Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for
>   enthusiasts and power users of the Android operating system. It's 100%
>   free, no registration required.

It's actually one of the more active [StackExchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: +1 Thanks, didn't know about it, I guess I'll just post my Android questions there. Superuser is limiting itself so much that it has become effectively useless.

Comment: is there anyway to notify the user of this BEFORE it is posted. I mean there's a 'it appears your question is subjective' notification. Something similar perhaps?